# Javascript addition of input values results concatnaing them

Tags: javascript

Following code instead of returning the addition results in appending the value of variable with the number. pl. help. thanks in advance.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>


  <input type="number" id="wd" value=1000>
  <br>
  Enter Height of chart
  <input type="number" id="ht" value=1000>
  <br>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var retWidth = document.getElementById('wd').value;
    var retHeight = document.getElementById('ht').value;
    wd1 = retWidth + 5; // hoping to get result 1005
    ht1 = retHeight + 5;
    console.log("wd1 = "+wd1)
    console.log("ht1 = "+ht1)
    </script>
  </body>

  </html>

  console log: 
  wd1 = 10005
  ht1 = 10005
```

Comment: `var retWidth = +document.getElementById('wd').value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parseInt() method to turn the strings back into numbers. Right now they are strings so adding two strings concatenates them, which is why you're getting 10005. 
Use parseInt(width)+5

Comment: Glad I was able to help. WC